# Error installing MySQL gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason I am having issues installing MySQL gem, which was not the case in the past. I have tried somethings without success. Such as:

Changing source `'https://rubygems.org'` to source `'http://rubygems.org'`.

Also installing `gem install mysql`.

As well as `sudo apt-get install mysql-dev` and then `gem install mysql`.

This is the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/kaka/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150701-13627-kzmz5m.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/kaka/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/kaka/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/kaka/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.18/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Could anyone help me?

Should I have installed mySQL server first to install this gem?

Comment: Did you try `sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'`

Comment: Try `gem install mysql2`

Comment: When I executed sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' I got sudo: gem: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql client/server first:
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client libmysqld-dev mysql-common

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** 
`brew install mysql && bundle`

**Long Answer**

I encountered this error when I didn't have the correct mysql installed. I decided to see where mysql was so I ran

```
$ which mysql
mysql: aliased to nocorrect mysql
```

Later I did some searching and found that `type mysql` is a better way to do this since it would have told me that the error above is specific issue where zsh aliases mysql to 'nocorrect mysql'.

Anyway, thinking I had no mysql I ran `brew install mysql` and rebundled which fixed the issue. So the problem was solved but if I run `which mysql` it still responds 'nocorrect mysql'. So the lesson of the day is to use type instead of which. Also to have mysql installed before installing the gem.